# Convert 2017-01-24T23:25:39 into datetime object

Tags: python

I have weird date format in logs: `2017-01-24T23:52:14`

I am trying to convert this string into datetime Python object like this:

`date_from_log = datetime.strptime('2017-01-24T23:52:14', '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S')`

but I get:

`ValueError: time data ' 2017-01-24T23:25:39 ' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S'`

What is wrong?

Comment: That's not a 'weird date format'. It's a widely used standard, called ISO 8601.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `%H` for hours!!

```
date_from_log = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
datetime(2017, 1, 24, 23, 52, 14)
```

Comment: Note `%I` is valid for `2017-01-24T10:52:14`. `%H` is for 24-hour clock time, and `%I` is for 12 hour clock time.